# creating a new list from another list but streamlining

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to create a function that receives two bits of information and returns two lists of floats based on information that is already present in a file:

Let's define the function as follows `get_cakes_size_colour()`, that should receive two strings as arguments: the name of the file, Cake size pattern. The function should return a list where the first element is a list of cake sizes and the second element a list of weight colors.

This was the bit of code that I tried:

```
def get_dimer_distance_energy(file_name, weight_size):
    one_cake_size = True
    cake_size = []
    cake_colour = []
    cake_colours = []

    with open(file_name,'r') as file:
       for line in file:
          if cake_size in line.split() and one_cake_size:
              cake_size_1 = line.split()[1]
              cake_size_A = float(cake_size_1)
              cake_size_2 = line.split()[2]
              cake_size_B = float(cake_size_2)
              cake_size_3 = line.split()[3]
              cake_size_C = float(cake_size_3)

              one_cake_size=False

          elif cake_size in line.split() and not one_cake_size:
              cake_size_4 = line.split()[1]
              cake_size_D = float(cake_size_4)
              cake_size_5 = line.split()[2]
              cake_size_E = float(cake_size_5)
              cake_size_6 = line.split()[3]
              cake_size_F = float(cake_size_6)

          one_cake_size=True
          cake_size = cake_size +[average_size((cake_size_A), (cake_size_B), (cake_size_C), (cake_size_D), (cake_size_E), (cake_size_F))]
          return cake_size

          if "cake colour" in line:
             cake_colour += [line.split()[3]]
             return cake_colour
             for item in cake_colour:
                 cake_colours.append(float(item))
                 return cake_colours
```

I should point out that I had already defined a function for average_size earlier which ran perfect and was as follows:

```
def average_size(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2):
    size = ( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 + (z1-z2)**2 )**0.5
    return size
```

There were two problems I found when running this code:

Firstly, I found that the return function does not return lists and was wondering if there were any amends to this. I tried looking for the solution to this on the site and could not find any that worked.

Secondly, I found that when running this code, it would return that any of the elements in the average_size function where instead it would return local variable referenced before assignment.

Comment: you return "cakes" but I don't see it defined anywhere else before?

Comment: sorry an error i realised. still hasn't solved problem

Comment: `1_cake_size`: bad naming convention. Variables should *never* start with a number.

Comment: amended but still makes no difference

Comment: It's still hard to tell what you're doing though. you're returning 3 different variables: `cake_size`, `cake_colour`, and `cake_colours`. you also realize that if you put `elif` instead of `if` and the first condition is met, the *whole* elif statement is ignored regardless if you set `one_cake_size` to False or True.

Comment: I don't actually see why an `elif` statement is necessary, it's doing the same thing. even if the first `if` statement failed, `one_cake_size` would remain true, and True + False = False. Nothing in your `elif` block would be executed. Either way, just doing one or the other and expecting both (in your `average_size` function call) would lead to a reference error.

Comment: cake_size is a list of floats

Comment: cake_colour is a list of strings

Comment: cake_colours is a list of floats.

Comment: i kind of used cake_colour to extract each of the different cake colours from the file (as there where multiple colours in the file) and cake_colours to convert the list of strings produced by cake_colour into cake_colours

Comment: Could you include a snippet of what the file looks like

Comment: Because I'm suspecting the issue is here: *if cake_size in line.split()*. `cake_size` is an empty list. `line.split()` gives you a list of strings, so finding a list in a string will return False

Comment: I can't because its a concept of a different file

Comment: I know I meant the other file that has the cake sizes and colours

Comment: it does not exist

Comment: there is another file but i cannot share that with you

Comment: its just a question of using 2 strings to extract 2 lists of floats from the file. when run on its own and not defined as a function it would provide me with a  list of results but it cannot do that when defined as a function